# Scipy different result distributive law

Tags: python, scipy, dot-product

I am using scipy to calculate dual affine scaling algorithm.

In the final part of the iteration step, I get different results when calculating control value sk.

```
s_k_control = c - (AT.dot(y_k) + AT.dot(t_k * (AHAT_inv.dot(b))))
print("SK_control 1:",np.min(s_k_control))

s_k_control = c - AT.dot(y_k + (t_k * (AHAT_inv.dot(b))))
print("SK_control 2:",np.min(s_k_control))

y_k_1 = y_k + t_k * (AHAT_inv.dot(b))

s_k_control = c - AT.dot(y_k_1)
print("SK_control 3:",np.min(s_k_control))
```

t_k is scalar and other variables are all sparse matrices (csc_matrix)

If I am not completely wrong, due to the distributive law of dot product ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_first_properties)), the above code should return same result in all three cases.

Instead, I get following result:

```
SK_control 1: 0.026123046875
SK_control 2: 0.0
SK_control 3: 0.0
```

What can I do to calculate y_k_1 in a way, that subsequent calculation of sk delivers the same result as the first control?

**Edit:**

Here is the original problem:

There is constraint: `s_next = c - A.T * y_next >= 0`

Use constraint and following formula to calculate step size `t`:

```
y_next = y_prev + t(AHA.T)^(-1)*b
```

- `A` is a sparse matrix of shape `(355,729)`
- `c` is vector of ones `(729,1)`
- `b` is vector of ones `(355,1)`
- first `y_prev` (`y_0`) is vector of zeros `(355,1)`
- `t` is a scalar, but in order to find it, I have to calculate the
  vector `t*`, and then take the smallest item from `t*` and multiply it by
  some factor `0 < beta < 1` (usually `0.9` or similar)

What I have tried:

1. Analytically calculating `t*` (by inserting the formula in the constraint with `s_next = 0`:

   ```
   t* = (c - A.T * y_prev)/(A.T(AHA.T)^(-1) * b)
   ```
2. calculating `y_next` using scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve from constraint:

   ```
   A.T * y_next = c
   ```

   (actually `A * A.T * y_next = A * c`, because `A` and therefore `A.T` are not quadratic)

   and then calculating `t*` like this:

   ```
   t* = (y_next - y_prev)/(AHA.T)^(-1) * b
   ```

Neither method gives the expected result.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that I am having problem with calculating the inverse of (AHA.T). When I test it (AHA.T) * (AHA.T)^-1 I dont get an identity matrix, but something completely random:

```
AHAT = (A * H * A.T).todense()
print(AHAT)
[[9. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 9. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 9. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]]
print(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(AHAT), AHAT))
[[ 6.43630605e+16 -3.53205583e+17  1.82309332e+16 ... -2.47507371e+15
   1.93886558e+15 -4.17941428e+15]
 [ 7.72005634e+16 -1.32187302e+17 -1.82278681e+16 ... -1.51094942e+16
  -1.67465411e+16  4.12101169e+15]
 [ 8.58099974e+14  1.89665457e+16 -1.23638446e+16 ... -3.81892219e+15
  -2.21686073e+15  2.61939698e+15]
 ...
 [ 4.44089210e-16 -5.32907052e-15  1.72084569e-15 ...  1.00000000e+00
   1.66533454e-16  1.31838984e-16]
 [ 6.66133815e-16 -1.77635684e-15  1.99840144e-15 ... -8.18789481e-16
   1.00000000e+00 -7.97972799e-16]
 [-1.11022302e-15  3.10862447e-15 -4.44089210e-16 ...  9.99200722e-16
   3.88578059e-16  1.00000000e+00]]
```

The inverse itself looks like this:

```
[[-6.10708114e+14 -4.24172270e+16 -1.62348045e+14 ... -1.80059454e-01
   7.58665399e-02  9.93203316e-01]
 [-2.81790056e+15 -8.26584741e+15  3.08108915e+14 ... -1.06861647e+02
  -1.96226676e-01  7.66381784e-01]
 [-4.36162847e+13  5.27325574e+15 -1.20358871e+15 ... -7.79860964e+00
  -3.24595030e-01 -1.50920847e-01]
 ...
 [ 9.20066618e-02  1.39924661e+00 -5.81619213e-02 ...  1.52230844e+00
   1.14720794e-02 -3.70994069e-02]
 [-2.31455053e-01  2.33160131e+00 -3.65460727e-02 ...  1.14720794e-02
   1.52976177e+00 -1.95029578e-02]
 [ 1.44223299e-01 -1.10202460e+00 -7.57449990e-02 ... -3.70994069e-02
  -1.95029578e-02  1.52462702e+00]]
```

Is there a possibility to avoid using inverse and still calculate the t_k?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that all 3 versions should be computing the same result. There could be some
variation since floating-point arithmetic is neither associative nor distributive:

```
In [147]: ((0.1+0.2)+0.3) != (0.1+(0.2+0.3))
Out[147]: True

In [153]: 0.3*(0.1+0.2) != 0.3*0.1 + 0.3*0.2
Out[153]: True
```

Couple that with multiplication by a large number:

```
In [164]: 1e15 * ((0.1+0.2)+0.3) - 1e15 * (0.1+(0.2+0.3))
Out[164]: 0.125
```

and the discrepancy can become significant.

But in the typical case your code works as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse
# np.random.seed(2019)

K, M, N, P = 100, 200, 300, 400
AT = sparse.random(K, M, density=0.001, format='csc')
y_k = sparse.random(M, P, density=0.001, format='csc')
t_k = np.exp(1)
AHAT_inv = sparse.random(M, N, density=0.001, format='csc')
b = sparse.random(N, P, density=0.0001, format='csc')
c = sparse.random(K, P, density=0.001, format='csc')

s_k_control = c - (AT.dot(y_k) + AT.dot(t_k * (AHAT_inv.dot(b))))
print("SK_control 1:", s_k_control.min())

s_k_control = c - AT.dot(y_k + (t_k * (AHAT_inv.dot(b))))
print("SK_control 2:", s_k_control.min())

y_k_1 = y_k + t_k * (AHAT_inv.dot(b))

s_k_control = c - AT.dot(y_k_1)
print("SK_control 3:", s_k_control.min())
```

prints a result such as

```
SK_control 1: -0.6701900742964602
SK_control 2: -0.6701900742964602
SK_control 3: -0.6701900742964602
```

For us to investigate your situation further, it would be very helpful if you
can produce a runnable, reproducable example which demonstrates the discrepancy.

---

Note that there is a [warning in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information) that **strongly discourages** applying NumPy functions directly to sparse matrices, "*because NumPy may not properly convert them for computations, leading to unexpected (and incorrect) results*". Use sparse matrix methods when available instead. Therefore, instead of `np.min(s_k_control)`, use `s_k_control.min()`.

If not available, and you can't devise a different method, it is recommended that you convert the sparse matrix to a NumPy array before applying any NumPy function.

This issue does not seem to be the cause of the problem in your case, but it is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the solution.

The right way is to completely avoid calculating the inverse.

If we have a linear problem `Ax = b`, the solution is: `x = A^(-1)*b`

Python has already the functions to calculate this solution, for instance scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.

So if I need to calculate `(AHA.T)^(-1) * b`, I just need to call `spsolve(A * H * A.T, b)`.

My calculation for t looks like this: `t_k = (c - A.T * y_k)/(A.T * spsolve(A * H * A.T, b))`

This gives me a stable solution and my entire algorithm converges within 20 iterations.

Comment: If you check `numpy.linalg.cond` for what you're trying to invert it's probably huge.

Comment: That is true. It was in the range of 1e+17. Also, the determinant was zero.